# Java Graphics "Bouncing Ball" Program

Tags: java, swing, graphics

This is my first Graphical Java program and what I'm trying to do is re-create a simple classic program where I have multiple balls bouncing in a `JFrame` window.

So far I have successfully been able to get one ball to bounce around using code inside the `run()` method. That works for one ball object that I create, but now I want to have many balls so I'm trying to create a method in my `Ball` class that will make each ball object that I create bounce in my "ball world" independently.

Right now all I care about is them bouncing off the walls, not each other (I will figure that out later).

**The problem:** In my `ballMove(int, int, int, int)` method I have four `int` parameters where the first two parameters are the `width` and `height` of the `window`, and the last two parameters are the `Xspeed`, and `Yspeed`. When I go through my `if statements` it will temperately set the `x` and `y speed` parameters to negative when the ball hits the right or bottom wall, but when the `run()` method executes the `ballMove(int, int, int, int)` method again, they go back to being positive and the balls disappear from the window. I have tried using a bunch of `getter` and `setter` methods in my ball class. I have tried temporary variables within my `ballMove(int, int, int, int)` method. Nothing I've tried works.

**Question:** By using my `Ball` class method, how do I prevent my parameters `Xspeed` and `Yspeed` from reinitializing my instance speed variables to positive when the ball(s) collide with the walls?

Because I'm new to graphical programming any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int width = 800;
    private int height= 600;
    private int ballRadius = 50;

    private Random rand = new Random();

    //Create and initialize a ball object
    public Ball ball = new Ball(Color.BLUE, ballRadius, ballRadius, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500));
    //public Ball ball2 = new Ball(Color.RED, ballRadius, ballRadius, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500));
    //public Ball ball3 = new Ball(Color.GREEN, ballRadius, ballRadius, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500));
    //public Ball ball4 = new Ball(Color.ORANGE, ballRadius, ballRadius, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500));
    //public Ball ball5 = new Ball(Color.YELLOW, ballRadius, ballRadius, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500));
    //constructor
    public Main(){

        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    //Paint the ball(s)
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(ball.getColor());
        g.fillOval(ball.getBallX(), ball.getBallY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());
        //g.setColor(ball2.getColor());
        //g.fillOval(ball2.getBallX(), ball2.getBallY(), ball2.getWidth(), ball2.getHeight());
        //g.setColor(ball3.getColor());
        //g.fillOval(ball3.getBallX(), ball3.getBallY(), ball3.getWidth(), ball3.getHeight());
        //g.setColor(ball4.getColor());
        //g.fillOval(ball4.getBallX(), ball4.getBallY(), ball4.getWidth(), ball4.getHeight());
        //g.setColor(ball5.getColor());
        //g.fillOval(ball5.getBallX(), ball5.getBallY(), ball5.getWidth(), ball5.getHeight());
    }
    //Run the program
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.run();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ball.ballMove(width, height, 20, 5);
            repaint();
            //ball2.ballMove(width, height, 15, 3);
            //repaint();
            //ball3.ballMove(width, height, 3, 20);
            //repaint();
            //ball4.ballMove(width, height, 10, 10);
            //repaint();
            //ball5.ballMove(width, height, 10, 20);
            //repaint();


        }
    }


}
```

Here is my `Ball` class

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Ball extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int width, height, ball_X, ball_Y;
    private int Xspeed;
    private int Yspeed;
    private Color color;
    public Ball(Color color, int width, int height, int ball_X, int ball_Y){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
        this.ball_X = ball_X;
        this.ball_Y = ball_Y;
    }
    public Color getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }
    public int getWidth(){
        return this.width;
    }
    public int getHeight(){
        return this.height;
    }
    public int getBallX(){
        return this.ball_X;
    }
    public int getBallY(){
        return this.ball_Y;
    }
    public void setSpeedX(int x){
        this.Xspeed = x;
    }
    public void setSpeedY(int x){
        this.Yspeed = x;
    }
    public int getSpeedX(){
        return this.Xspeed;
    }
    public int getSpeedY(){
        return this.Yspeed;
    }
    public void setBallX(int x){
        this.ball_X = x;
    }
    public void setBallY(int y){
        this.ball_Y = y;
    }
    public void ballMove(int X, int Y, int xSpeed, int ySpeed){

        //initialize Xspeed and Yspeed with the parameters of the function
        this.setSpeedX(xSpeed);
        this.setSpeedY(ySpeed);
        //Moves the balls by adding the set speed to the position of the balls each time thread is executed
        this.setBallX(this.getBallX() + this.getSpeedX());
        this.setBallY(this.getBallY() + this.getSpeedY());
        //When the balls hit the walls they are suppose to bounce back until they hit another wall.
        if(this.getBallX() + 50 >= X){
            this.setSpeedX(-xSpeed);
        }
        if(this.getBallY() + 50 >= Y){
            this.setSpeedY(-ySpeed);
        }
        if(this.getBallX() + 25 <= 0){
            this.setBallX(xSpeed);
        }
        if(this.getBallY() + 25 <= 0){
            this.setSpeedY(ySpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you taking arguments in the `move()` method. It shouldn't take any arguments, and just be using the Ball state

Comment: 1) use Swing `Timer` instead `Thread.sleep()`. 2) Your problem in `ballMove()` method in `this.setSpeedX(xSpeed);this.setSpeedY(ySpeed);` lines. 3) Instead paint on `JFrame` use `JPanel` and method `paintComponent()`

Comment: @alex2410 What's the difference between `JFrame` and `JPanel`, and why would `JPanel` be a better choice to use for a program like this? What about using the Applet class? Could I use that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right there:

`ball.ballMove(width, height, 20, 5);`

Since this is a loop, every time it's called you make it move in the same direction. You're inverting the speed at the end of ballmove if it hits a wall but it doesn't matter because next time you call it, the ball still moves towards +20, +5.

My suggestion is to add the speed parameters when you create your instance of ball and have the ballmove update its own speed.

`ball.ballMove(width, height);`

Other suggestion: Put your collision check before actually moving the ball. That way you can make sure you're not going in the wrong direction before actually moving it.

Now, another problem is that in your main, you're calling the `run()` method of your runnable. Run gets executed on the current thread. You'd need to do something like this:

`Thread t = new Thread(main);
 t.start();`

To do drawings and calculations independently of the JFrame.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your first suggestion and it works perfectly!